# How to patch a click cli app for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, click, patch

I have a cli tool written in Python using Click:

cli/main.py

```
import click
from datetime import *
from .utils import fn

@click.group(invoke_without_command=True, context_settings = { 'ignore_unknown_options': True, 'allow_extra_args': True })
@click.argument('args', nargs=-1)
def cli(args):
    print(fn())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli([])
```

cli/utils.py

```
def fn():
    return("Example")
```

tests/test.py

```
from click.testing import CliRunner
from mock import *

from cli.main import cli

@patch('cli.utils.fn')
class Test:
    def test_patch_fn(self, mock_fn: Mock):
        
        mock_fn.return_value = "Mocked return"

        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(cli, [])

        assert result.exit_code == 0
        assert result.stdout == "Mocked return"
```

Running the test gives:

```
FAILED tests/test.py::Test::test_patch_fn - AssertionError: assert 'Example\n' == 'Mocked return'
```

ok, so the patching failed.  I tried the following with varying results:

| patch string | error |
| --- | --- |
| `cli.main.cli.utils.fn` | `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cli.main.cli'; 'cli.main' is not a package` |
| `tests.test.cli.fn` | `AttributeError: <Group cli> does not have the attribute 'fn'` |
| `cli.fn` | `AttributeError: <module 'cli' from '/home/user/code/click-example/cli/__init__.py'> does not have the attribute 'fn'` |
| `cli.main.cli.fn` | `AttributeError: <Group cli> does not have the attribute 'fn'` |

What is the magic string I need to make this work?

Comment: If in the module click/testing.py is present `from cli.utils import fn` try with `@patch('click.testing.fn')`. Otherwise edit your question and add the content of the module `click/testing.py` wich contains the definition of the class `CliRunner`

Comment: click.testing is a standard click module: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/testing/

Comment: Sorry. Try with `@patch('cli.main.fn')`.